# Hexagonal filling of 2D array

Tags: python

I am trying to fill an array with unique integers (except for 0) in such a fashion:

```
# range(0, 37)
[[ 0,  0,  0, 36, 19, 20, 21],
 [ 0,  0, 35, 18,  7,  8, 22],
 [ 0, 34, 17,  6,  1,  9, 23],
 [33, 16,  5,  0,  2, 10, 24],
 [32, 15,  4,  3, 11, 25,  0],
 [31, 14, 13, 12, 26,  0,  0],
 [30, 29, 28, 27,  0,  0,  0]]
```

(This represents hex grid as 2D array)

How to figure out the size of 2D array (width and height) before it is filled?
How to determine the coordinate at which the next integer should be placed?

Thanks to @Błotosmętek I am now able to figure out the size of the array:

```
def array_size(n):
    k = 0
    while n > 0:
        k += 1
        n -= 6 * k
    return 2 * k + 1
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @EricDuminil Not much. I have updated the question, but I still don't know from where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

To figure out how to place values in given manner, we need to figure out coordinates delta for each item.

For the sake of explanation, I will use `n = 60` elements.

To do that, we need to know the size of the array we will get, this can be accomplished by what @Błotosmętek suggested:

```
def array_size(n):
k = 0
while n > 0:
    k += 1
    n -= 6 * k
return 2 * k + 1

array_size = array_size(n)
```

(By the way, thanks for great heads-up.)
Now, we need the coordinates for array center, which is pretty easy:

```
# This is (4, 4), the exact coordinates we need for said amount of items (60)
array_center = (array_size // 2, array_size // 2)
```

Next, we get the deltas. I am not sure that this is the best way to do so, but anyway:

```
def get_coordinates_delta(n):
    x = [0]
    x_ones = 1
    x_zeroes = 1
    while len(x) <= n:
        x += ([1] * x_ones + [0] * x_zeroes + [-1] * (x_ones + 1) + [0] * x_zeroes)
        x_ones += 2
        x_zeroes += 1

    y = [0, -1]
    y_ones = 2
    y_zeroes = 1
    while len(y) <= n:
        y += ([1] * y_ones + [0] * y_zeroes + [-1] * (y_ones + 1) + [0] * y_zeroes)
        y_ones += 2
        y_zeroes += 1
    return [x for x in zip(x[:n], y[:n])]

coordinates_delta = get_coordinates_delta(n)
```

And now the fun part, we place everything we have onto the grid:

```
def fill_matrix():
    matrix = [[0] * array_size for _ in range(array_size)]
    x, y = array_center
    for item, (dx, dy) in zip(range(n), coordinates_delta):
        x += dx
        y += dy
        matrix[y][x] = item
    return matrix

matrix = fill_matrix()
```

Voila,

```
for line in matrix:
    print(line)
```

gives us this:

```
[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 37, 38, 39, 40]
[ 0,  0,  0, 59, 36, 19, 20, 21, 41]
[ 0,  0, 58, 35, 18,  7,  8, 22, 42]
[ 0, 57, 34, 17,  6,  1,  9, 23, 43]
[56, 33, 16,  5,  0,  2, 10, 24, 44]
[55, 32, 15,  4,  3, 11, 25, 45,  0]
[54, 31, 14, 13, 12, 26, 46,  0,  0]
[53, 30, 29, 28, 27, 47,  0,  0,  0]
[52, 51, 50, 49, 48,  0,  0,  0,  0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use np.put to place values at the target indices.This is my solution,change it as you wish

```
import numpy as np

a = np.empty(49)
b = np.arange(0, 48, 1)
ind = np.arange(len(a))
np.put(a, ind, b)
a1 = np.reshape(a, (7, 7), order='F')
print(a1)
```

And you gave this array

```
[[  0.   7.  14.  21.  28.  35.  42.]
 [  1.   8.  15.  22.  29.  36.  43.]
 [  2.   9.  16.  23.  30.  37.  44.]
 [  3.  10.  17.  24.  31.  38.  45.]
 [  4.  11.  18.  25.  32.  39.  46.]
 [  5.  12.  19.  26.  33.  40.  47.]
 [  6.  13.  20.  27.  34.  41.   0.]]
```

Comment: Thank you, now I know how to place values.
Do you have an idea on how to place them from center and in hexagonal fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the dimensions is relatively easy: notice that your smallest "hexagon" is one element, then you add 6 elements around it, then 12, then 18… every loop around the centre adds 6*k numbers, where k=1, 2, … and the dimensions for k loops are 2*k+1 by 2*k+1. So, your function should work like this:

```
def array_size(n):
    k = 0
    while n > 0:
        k += 1
        n -= 6 * k
    return 2 * k + 1
```

so for example `array_size(36) == 7`.

Now, placing your numbers correctly is another story…

```
N=36
n=array_size(N)
t = [ ['.'] * n for _ in range(n) ]

x = y = (n-1)//2
d = ((0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, 0))
k = 0
t[y][x] = 0
y -= 1
x += 1
t[y][x] = 1
i = 1
while i<N:
    nx = x + d[k][0]
    ny = y + d[k][1]
    px = x + d[(k+1) % 6][0]
    py = y + d[(k+1) % 6][1]
    if t[py][px] != '.':
        x, y = nx, ny
        i += 1
        t[y][x] = i
    else:
        k = (k+1) % 6

for row in t:
    print("".join(("{:>3} ".format(p if p != '.' else 0) for p in row)))
print()
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Although, I'd add `n -= 1` before the loop, since 37, 19 and 7 tiles should not add an empty space. I'll upvote your answer as soon as I have 15 reputation :)

Comment: So where are you going to put 37 in a 7 x 7 array? `n` here is the last number to include, **not** the total quantity of numbers (which is greater by 1 since you start counting from 0)

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are correct. I have the same array on my whiteboard but starting from 1, not 0. Got myself puzzled.

Comment: BTW, is it a purely academic exercise or does this have a practical application? Inquiring minds want to know…

Comment: It is purely academic exercise. I used to participate in development of Pokemon Go maps, and there was a similar task. My python level was far from enough to understand the code in that part, so now I am kinda catching up.

Comment: Then you might be interested with the solution I came up with - see edited answer.